# How can i write 300 of the same word in an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops

How to write a word 300 times in an array with code in C like for ex. (wordwordword....)
I am amateur. If i wrote bad i am sorry.

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,k=0,boyut;
    char word[10]={"word"};
    char alotWord[300][4];

    for(i=0;i<300;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
           word[j]=alotWord[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `printf` will print that word for you without requiring that second `for` loop.

Comment: And if you're just copying that word into a 300 slot array, `strcpy` will work nicely.

Comment: The assignation operator (`=`) assigns it right side to its left side. You should write `alotWord[i][j] = word[j]`. But beware, you will have raw arrays but not C-strings in `alotWord` because you failed to add the terminating null characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

The first is that you copy *from* the uninitialized `alotWord[i]`, with `word` being the destination. It should be the opposite way around.

The second problem is that you seem to forget that C strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. Once you fix the copying you never null-terminate your strings. You don't actually have space for adding the null-terminator.

With that said, don't do string copying yourself, use the standard `strcpy` instead:

```
char alotWord[300][sizeof word];  // Use sizeof to make sure that the word fits

for(i=0;i<300;i++)
{
    // Copy from word into alotWord[i]
    strcpy(alotWord[i], word);
}
```

And if all you want to do is *print* the word a lot of times you don't need the array at all:

```
for(i=0;i<300;i++)
{
    printf("%s", word);
}
```